# Migrate from react-router to react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby, react-router-dom, auth0

I am trying to complete this tutorial [Securing Gatsby With Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-gatsby-with-auth0/), but have hit a roadblock due to reach/router not being compatible with react 17. After a bit of googling around, I found this issue [Which router project to use moving forward](https://github.com/reach/router/issues/493) which has a migration guide: [Migrate to React Router from Reach](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/reach)

However, as a beginner, I am not well versed enough to make sense of what it contains.

The source code from the tutorial is as follows:

```
import React from "react"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const Home = () => <p>Home</p>
const Settings = () => <p>Settings</p>
const Billing = () => <p>Billing</p>

const Account = () => (
  <>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/account">Home</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="/account/settings">Settings</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="/account/billing">Billing</Link>{" "}
    </nav>
    <Router>
      <Home path="/account" />
      <Settings path="/account/settings" />
      <Billing path="/account/billing" />
    </Router>
  </>
)

export default Account
```

From the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/reach#update-router-to-routes) update router to routes, I have changed this to:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => <p>Home</p>
const Settings = () => <p>Settings</p>
const Billing = () => <p>Billing</p>

const Account = () => (
  <>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/account">Home</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="/account/settings">Settings</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="/account/billing">Billing</Link>{" "}
    </nav>
    <Routes>
      <Home path="/account" />
      <Settings path="/account/settings" />
      <Billing path="/account/billing" />
    </Routes>
  </>
)

export default Account
```

So in essence, replace Router with Routes. Now this compiles successfully, but fails at run time with this error:

> [Home] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>`
> must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

So Home, Settings, and Billing are deemed not to be `<Route\>` or `<React.Fragment\>`

This is a simple example, for somebody well versed in react-router. I am just learning this stuff so having some difficulty. I have asked auth0 to update this tutorial but have no idea when this will be actioned, if ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Routes` component only replaces the `Switch` component from `react-router-dom` v5, but is required to wrap `Route` components in v6. The routed components, `Home`, etc... need to be rendered by a `Route`.

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => <p>Home</p>
const Settings = () => <p>Settings</p>
const Billing = () => <p>Billing</p>

const Account = () => (
  <>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/account">Home</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="/account/settings">Settings</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="/account/billing">Billing</Link>{" "}
    </nav>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/account" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/account/settings" element={<Settings />} />
      <Route path="/account/billing" element={<Billing />} />
    </Routes>
  </>
);
```